# Passing a parameter to a function to get a string back

Tags: vb.net, parameters

I think this is relatively a simple question but it seems like I've been having a small issue with this...

I have a form where I try to pass a parameter to a function and get a string back in return with a value

```
 ParmValue = "Juarez"

 dim CheckValue = GetValueFromFunction(parmValue)

 Private Sub GetValueFromFunction (ByVal Optional ValueFromFunc as string)
    'do stuff
    getValueFromFunction = "OK"

    or

    getValueFromFuncton="NOTOK"

    return GetValueFromFunction
 End sub
```

Basically I'm looking to get a string value back from my GetValueFromFunction so that CheckValue holds that value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the real code? Don't mix this old and ugly vb6 syntax with .NET. Return the return value and don't assign it to the method. So declare a local variable in the method. Do your stuff and then assign the correct value to that variable. Finally return it.

Comment: That wont compile since your optional param doesnt have a default value, and under option strict you need to declare a return type.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I do mainy vb6 which is why I'm trying to do the same here

Comment: @Plutonix ya it says Return statement in sub cannot return a value

Comment: @BobSki: overlooked, make it a `Function` and append `As String`

Comment: Consider overloads aswell. Optional parameters are bad practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return something from a [`Sub`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha.aspx); it has to be a [`Function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx):

```
Private Function GetValueFromFunction(Optional ValueFromFunc as String = Nothing) As String
    Dim returnValue As String 
    'do stuff... 
    If someCondition Then
        returnValue = "OK"
    Else
        returnValue = "NOTOK"
    End If

    Return returnValue 
End Function
```

A [`Function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx) is a method that returns something, whereas a [`Sub`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha.aspx) is a method that doesn't return something (it's more like an action). In C#, a `Sub` would return `void`.

Comment: `Optional parameters must specify a default value.`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are returning a value, you need to use a `Function`. Your code is wrong because it declares a `Sub` (procedure).

The correct use of a `Function` is:

```
Private Function GetValueFromFunction (ByVal ValueFromFunc As String) As String
   ' do stuff
    GetValueFromFunction = "OK"

    ' or

    GetValueFromFunction = "NOTOK"

    Return GetValueFromFunction
End Function
```

> Note the use of `As String`. This is to dictate the return type of your `Function`.